# I want to change condition of zero subtotal checkout payment method in magento-2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, grand-total

I have Grand total value is 0.5.If grandtotal price is less than 1,we placed order by free payment method.How it can achieve in Magento-2.1?

Answer (score 0):

Create a shopping cart price rule with the following values:

**Rule Information:**

- Customer Groups: NOT LOGGED IN, General, Wholesale, Retailer (and/or any other if you have custom customer groups)
- Coupon: No Coupon
- Uses per Customer: 0

**Conditions:**

- If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE:
      Subtotal  equals or less than  0.5

**Actions:**

- Apply: Percent of product price discount
- Discount Amount: 100

Rest conditions you can manage as per your requirement.

Comment: If I have grandtotal is less than 1 like 0.1 to 0.9 after apply Reward Amount and Coupon Discount.I want to placed order using free method in this case.

Comment: Have you tried above solution?